# Python throws "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" whyle importing the selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to import selenium to start a scratch project but getting error constantly, I have tried couple of solution but non has worked for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

The error I get is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\ruben\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 5, in
>
> driver = webdriver.chrome() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Couldn't find any cure for this

I have tried to add a path of location of the webdriver to `webdriver.chrome()` as an argument, but that doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

It seams that there is a **chrome** folder in the system which has been autocompleted when I hit the TAB button. so the issue is the chrome should be upper case like this.

```
webdriver.Chrome()
```

hope this will help anybody in case the issue accures.